# How to get all contributions of a wikipedia user?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

Given a Wikipedia user/editor id and a timeframe, is there a way in Python to get details about all the contributions/edits made the user/editor? I want to fetch details like page edited, action taken, bytes added/deleted in case of revision, and comments (if any). Is this possible at all?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`pywikibot`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot)’s `User` class has a `.contributions()` method you can use to iterate over all contributions for a user.

It returns a generator that, for each edit, yields a tuple of `(pywikibot.Page, oldid, pywikibot.Timestamp, comment)`. You don’t get the diff, but you can retrieve the page at this point (`page.getOldVersion(oldid=…)`) and do the diff from the point just before.

Simple code example:

```py
from pywikibot import Site, User

user = User(Site(), "SanMelkote")
for page, oldid, ts, comment in user.contributions():
    print(Page.title(), comment)
```